# Parsing errors in sort on using customValueSourceParsers in sort field

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a valueSourceParser which is used for functional boosting.

It looks like svp("abc","xyz"), whenever I am putting this in sort field, it's giving a 400 with the following message

> "msg": "sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: svp("abc","xyz")"

This is a parsing related issue imo. Because I have another valueSourceParser which takes in just one single valueSource/argument and the sort works just fine.
On moving to multiple valueSourcess/args, this issue comes up.

I used the concept of placeholders to solve this. Assigning it to a variable and invoking the variable at sort field.

k=svp("abc","xyz")
sort=$k desc

But that didn't seem to work.

Any other approach that anyone is aware of ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by simply putting a {!func} tag in front of the function

sort={!func}svp("abc","xyz") asc